# no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char [8]" to "std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t>>"

Tags: c++

First. I want to say, that I am not C++ programmer. 
The outlook string generates an error in visual studio 2015 with the message that is in the title.

```
HWND windowHandle = (HWND)FindProcessId("outlook");
```

The function definition:

```
DWORD FindProcessId(const std::wstring& processName)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 processInfo;
    processInfo.dwSize = sizeof(processInfo);

    HANDLE processesSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    if (processesSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    Process32First(processesSnapshot, &processInfo);
    if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
    {
        CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
        return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
    }

    while (Process32Next(processesSnapshot, &processInfo))
    {
        if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
        {
            CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
            return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error on the outlook string,

```
HWND windowHandle = (HWND)FindProcessId(**"outlook"**);
```

I also put a cast to HWND, but I am not sure if I get any run-time compilation errors.

Comment: `FindProcessId(L"outlook")`

Comment: Prefix your string with L like L"outlook" if you need wide string wstring.

Comment: Which character set did you you? If you used Unicode, you need to call `FindProcessId(L"outlook")` as Alan recommended, if you used ANSI, you need to change your signature to `DWORD FindProcessId(const std::string& processName)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got error beacause you are passing ASCII string whereas signature expects wide string.

Try

```
HWND windowHandle = (HWND)FindProcessId(L"outlook");
```

Your signature

```
DWORD FindProcessId(const std::wstring& processName)
```

mentions that it takes `wstring` which is wide string. And you are passing "outlook" which is compatible with `const string&`. Hence, you got compile error.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking a string literal to function as `std::wstring &` which isn't allowed.
Probably, you can fix by taking string as `std::wstring const &`,

`DWORD FindProcessId(std::wstring const & processName)`

Since `"outlook"` literal is an rvalue, it can't binded to a `non-const` reference but it is legal to bind it to a `const` reference.

Comment: I have checked that fix works. Could you please elaborate why downvote?

Comment: `std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t>>` is a `std::wstring` Hence neither `std::string&` nor `std::string const &` is correct

Comment: OK, I corrected it. But I hope that reasoning about non-const reference is correct. I mistakenly put string instead of wstring.

Comment: Are you sure whether it works or not? What happened it `TCHAR` is a unicode charactor `wchar_t`

Comment: I am sure about my answer to question asked. Not sure about what you are saying? Anyway my only point is that it could be fixed by binding literal to a const reference. That's it!

Comment: [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842072.aspx) said nothing if `TCHAR` is a Win32 character string that can be used to describe Unicode strings. It may be a `wchar_t` if Unicode flags is set